# how to reinstall cudnn？

Tags: c++, linux, lua

After install Cudnn.4.0.4, I find if I want to run the code I have downloaded, I need a higher version of Cudnn. Then I download cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-prod.tgz and directly install by following order:

```
 $ sudo cp include/cudnn.h /usr/local/include
 $ sudo cp lib64/libcudnn.* /usr/local/lib
 $ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libcudnn.so.4.0.7 /usr/local/lib/libcudnn.so.4
 $ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libcudnn.so.4 /usr/local/lib/libcudnn.so
 $ sudo ldconfig -v
```

While I running `sudo ldconfig -v`, there is an error:

> /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.4 is not a symbolic link

I run the source code again and have the same error before I reinstall cudnn:

```
 luajit: /home/zhfu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/ffi.lua:1287: These bindings are for version 4005 or above, while the loaded CuDNN is version: 4004  
 Are you using an older version of CuDNN?
 stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/zhfu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/ffi.lua:1287: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/zhfu/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/init.lua:4: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./main.lua:329: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Can somebody helps me to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd say you either need to install version 4005 or downgrade something in lua... sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: 3Q, I have already fix the problem. Just delete all related files both in /usr/local/lib and in /usr/local/cuda/lib64

Comment: Post an answer if you have fixed it. It may help others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I update cuDNN to a newer version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137828/how-do-i-update-cudnn-to-a-newer-version)

Answer (score 5):

Just delete all related files both in `/usr/local/lib` and in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`
That's work for me.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux, it looks like this:

`sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda-xxx/lib64/libcudnn*`

cuda-xxx stand for cuda version: e.g 7.5 or 8.0

run the one of the following commands:

`sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libcudnn*`

or

`sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn*`

Answer (score 0):

if you installed CUDNN using the following command on RHEL / Centos,

```
sudo rpm -ivh libcudnn8-8.0.1.13-1.cuda11.0.x86_64.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh libcudnn8-devel-8.0.1.13-1.cuda11.0.x86_64.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh libcudnn8-doc-8.0.1.13-1.cuda11.0.x86_64.rpm
```

We can remove the same by using

```
sudo yum remove libcudnn*
```