# how do I update cuDNN to a newer version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, caffe, cudnn

the cuDNN installation manual says

> ALL PLATFORMS
>
> Extract the cuDNN archive to a directory of your choice, referred to below as .
>       Then follow the platform-specific instructions as follows.
>
> LINUX
>
> cd 
>       export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> Add  to your build and link process by adding -I to your compile
>       line and -L -lcudnn to your link line.

It seems that it simply adds `pwd` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so I guess just replacing the files in `pwd` will do the update.

But it seems not that simple as after I've done this I got a complaint from Theano saying

> cuDNN Version is too old. Update to v5, was 3007.

Answer (score 10):

1. replace `cudnn.h` in `dir/cuda/include/`
2. remove the old library files in `dir/cuda/lib64/`
3. add new library files to `dir/cuda/lib64/`

Comment: Also make sure that your system paths are set correctly.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a script which can be used to clean install a version of cuDNN or change the existing cuDNN to an older/a newer version. You can download the script from:

https://github.com/dnzzcn/cuDNNv

This is what the script does:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /usr/include/cudnn.h
rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcudnn*
rm -f /usr/local/cuda-*/lib64/*libcudnn*


cp -P packages/cudnn/include/cudnn.h /usr/include
cp -P packages/cudnn/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
chmod a+r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn*

rm -rf packages/cudnn
```

It performs the installation operations automatically for the version you need.

Comment: assuming `packages/` is in your `CWD`? also requires `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, packages folder is included in the repository directory. There is a python script that calls the bash script above for the desired cuDNN version; and although I'm not sure, it should work without sudo.

Comment: your application shows it has done the thing even when it hasn't.

Comment: deadcode can you check terminal output when you try to install cuDNN? If you see errors regarding permissions, try running cuDNNv with sudo.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but now we have conda. We don't need to manually replace these files anymore. `conda install cudnn` does all the trick.

Comment: This installed `cudnn` latest version `8.2.1.32` in the conda environment. However, when I run `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`, it still shows me version `7.5.1`. Any comments?

Comment: /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h is not the cudnn version conda installs. Conda installs cudnn to its local path, for example /path/to/conda/envs/env_name/lib . It works by changing the rpath in the binary file. You can read the blog post https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/101027069 if you can read Chinese.

Comment: How to install the latest minor version of a specifi major version (e.g 8.1)?

Comment: @liang `conda install -c conda-forge cudnn=8.1`