# CuDNN not compitable with tensorflow 1.11.0+Cuda9.0

Tags: tensorflow

i have problem when i try running object detection program with tensorflow.
i'm using :

Ubuntu 16.04
Tensorflow 1.11.0
Cuda 9.0
cuDNN 7.0.5

And my error is:

> 2020-01-02 08:53:57.535277: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:343] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.2.1.  CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
> Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

And i try get cuDNN minor and major.

```
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 0
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5
#define CUDNN_VERSION    (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)
```

What should I do? ,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `cudnn` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137828/how-do-i-update-cudnn-to-a-newer-version).

However, I prefer to use `conda` to install `cudnn`. This way, `conda install cudnn` works just fine. You don't need to manually replace some header files or so.