# How to delete cudnn from ubuntu?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, cudnn

I need cudnn 7 for my tensorflow version. But I can't delete cudnn.

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h84AA.png)

Update:

```
daniel@tales:~$ rm -r /usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libcudnn*
rm: can't delete '/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libcudnn*': didn't find this catalog
``
```

Comment: This answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311956/1161847) worked for me.

Comment: if you install using the deb file - you can open original installation - and using software installer - you can click the red rubbish bin to delete it.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed cudnn with dpkg, you can simply `dpkg --remove` each cudnn package. You can check which cudnn packages you installed with dpkg using `dpkg -l | grep cudnn`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few posts related to this. Here I'm posting for your help. Try below options:

1. Just delete all related files both in `/usr/local/lib` and in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` That's work for me.
2. In Linux, it looks like this:

   `rm -r /usr/local/cuda-xxx/lib64/libcudnn*`

cuda-xxx stand for cuda version: e.g 7.5 or 8.0

run one of the following commands:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libcudnn*
```

or

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn*
```

The details can be found here [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137582/how-to-reinstall-cudnn), [link-2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022631/how-do-i-completely-wipe-cuda-and-cudnn-off-my-ubuntu-16-04), [link-3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959835/how-to-remove-cuda-9-0-and-install-cuda-8-0-instead), [link-4](https://davidstutz.de/upgrading-cuda-and-installing-cudnn-for-caffe-and-tensorflow/)

Comment: Could you please post Traceback?

Answer (score 1):

I checked version with:

```
dpkg -l | grep cuda
```

Should appears to you a list of libcudnn files (in my case I had *libcudnn7 libcudnn7-dev*).

After checked your version, simply:

```
sudo dpkg --remove libcudnn7 libcudnn7-dev # in my situation
```

But the rule is:

```
sudo dpkg --remove NAME_OF_YOUR_PACKAGE
```

After these:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

For others details: [NVIDIA - Forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-uninstall-cuda-toolkit-and-cudnn-under-linux/47923/3)